# redirect from https to http under certain conditions with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm scratching my head on this one. I need to set up a rule so when someone goes to an address on my site with /members/ in the url it will automatically switch back to http from https.

so kinda like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.co.uk/$1
```

well I'm not so great with this type of problem so some help would be very much appreciated.

edit- current .htaccess

```
 #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(acatalog)
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// %{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Comment: You have to find out, to which port is bind SSL connection.

Comment: why? never heard that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(members/.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: no joy. cant seem to get anything other than just sending it all back to the home page with #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(acatalog)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301] to work :(

Comment: Pls post your current .htaccess in your question (not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^members/(.*) http://www.domain-name.co.uk/members/$1
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` checks whether https is used. Only if this is true, the RewriteRule will be active.

Comment: cant seem to get it to work. is there anything else i should know to get it to function?

Comment: You should place this .htaccess file inside the folder which contains the "members" folder. And you must not write `#` in front of every line as you have done it in your question.

Comment: yea i know # is a comment, i just copied it from the file. as it isn't working i commented it out.
also its in joomla so there is no members folder